# How to use Solr on Postgresql and index a table

Tags: postgresql, solr

I am new to Solr with the specific need to crawl existing database table and generate results.

Any online example/tutorial so far only explains about you give documents and it gets indexed, but not any indication of how to do same on database.

Can anyone please explain steps how to achieve this ?

Links like [this wiki](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DIHQuickStart) shows everything with jdbc driver and mysql so I even doubt if Solr supports this with .NET or not. My tech boundries are in C# and Postgresql

Comment: have you tried the [DIH](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Uploading+Structured+Data+Store+Data+with+the+Data+Import+Handler)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have stumpled over the included support for JDBC already, but you have to use the postgres JDBC driver. The example will be identical with the MySQL one, but you'll have to [use the proper URL for postgres instead](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/80/connect.html) and reference the JDBC driver (which will depend on which Postgres JDBC driver you use).

```
jdbc:postgresql://localhost/test
```

This is a configuration option in Solr, and isn't related to .NET or other external dependencies.

However, the other option is to write the indexing code yourself, and this can often be a good solution as it makes it easier to pre-process the content and apply certain logic before storing content in Solr. For .NET you have [Solrnet](https://github.com/mausch/SolrNet), a Solr client, that'll make it easy to both query from and submit documents to Solr.